# Remove one key from array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object 'myObjects':

```
let myObjects = {
  "obj1":["X1","1.2"],
  "obj2": "2",
  "obj3": "3"
};
```

I am trying to only remove the X1 from the obj1 section. I have tried doing:

```
delete obj1[0];
```

however end up with

```
 [null,"1.2"]
```

how do I get rid of the null?

Comment: `myObjects.obj1.splice(0,1)`

Comment: btw... `obj1` isn't an object... it's an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to remove element from `Array` not `Object`. In that case, you can use `Array.splice` as follows.

```js
let myObjects = {
  "obj1":["X1","1.2"],
  "obj2": "2",
  "obj3": "3"
};

delete myObjects.obj1.splice(0, 1);
console.log(myObjects);
```

Comment: Please search for duplicates instead of adding just another copy of an already written answer.

Comment: @Andreas finally I feel like I am not alone, especially when looking at the JS tag...

Comment: @MrUpsidown Quality >>> Reputation :)

Comment: What's the purpose of `delete`?